# Impossible to git push to a https GitLab repository: SSH passphrase wrongly asked each time

Tags: linux, ssh, git, gitlab

I have some SSH keys that, after entering my passphrases on a terminal, I use successfully to connect to some servers, in particular to push on `git` repositories.

My organization is testing a self hosted GitLab instance where, currently, we didn't succeed to enable SSH cloning. I created a repository from the UI of this GitLab instance and, because of the lack of SSH, cloned it via `https`. I made some changes then, from a terminal, committed and then tried to push. I tested from two machines:

1. a (GNU/Linux Debian) distant one (our server) where everything went smoothly,
2. a (GNU/Linux Mageia 9) local one where, each time, the following pop up (`qt5-ssh-askpass` I guess) appears:

   [image]

   And, even with a correct passphrase, this obviously fails since SSH is not enabled on our instance. After a first failure, the same popup appears again, with the same failure and the following error message appears:

   > remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See https://gitlab.gutenberg-asso.fr/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied.

A friend of mine tried the same procedure from many different machines, and didn't have such problems.

Do you understand what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

SSH keys cannot be used with the HTTP protocol.

If you cloned with HTTP and not SSH then the repo will have its "remote" set to use HTTP, meaning any push or pull will use that protocol.

If you want to use SSH keys for authentication then you must use ssh, the easiest way being to clone with SSH.

If you cannot get SSH working then you will need to use user passwords to authenticate.  This might possibly need enabling on the GitLab settings, I'm not familiar with GitLab only git.

Comment: You say that I will need to use user passwords to authenticate if (on the GitLab instance) I cannot get SSH working. But that's the point: in order to authenticate, I was able from a remote machine to use password and would like to do so from my local one; but, there, I systematically get this annoying popup which prevents me to to do so.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I'm not a GitLab expert I'm afraid. Have you tried something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43070129/453851 embedding the username and password in the URL?

Comment: It doesn't work, maybe because my password contains several special characters (though I replaced them by their ASCII valid format).

Answer (score 1):

Git supports a variety of ways to prompt the user, including askpass helpers using the same protocol as used by SSH.  This is because Git may run behind the scenes where the user has only a graphical interface (this is especially common on Windows, but not limited to that platform).  The askpass helper is passed a text prompt, which it is supposed to display to the user.

The askpass helper is set if the `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable is set (and in such a case, takes a program name), the `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable if that is not set, or the `core.askPass` configuration value.

It sounds like what is happening here is that you have an askpass helper configured (my guess is with `SSH_ASKPASS`), but it incorrectly displays a static prompt instead of the one given.  If that's the case, what you actually need to provide is a personal access token here, which should result in a successful push (provided it has the right scopes).

If you want to be prompted at the command line instead, you can unset the appropriate environment variables and configuration options, and then you'll see the prompt instead.  Note that if you haven't already [configured a credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials), you may want to do that so you don't need to enter your PAT every time.

Comment: Indeed, I'd like to be prompted at the command line instead. `echo $GIT_ASKPASS` returns nothing and `echo $SSH_ASKPASS` returns
`/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass`. I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: At your shell, you can do `unset SSH_ASKPASS`, which you may want to apply to your shell configuration as well for the future.